# Don't display pending edit counter if you've exhausted your suggested edit votes

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, suggested-edits, 10k-tools

Once a user has exhausted their (currently) 30 edit suggestion approval/rejections, the pending edit box in the top bar can still show up:

[image: rep bar, with protein]

You click through and see some edits suggested to vote yay or nay on.

But when trying to approve/reject you get the warning:

> Out of votes - you may only vote 30 times a day.

Don't tease me, bro!

Comment: Since now it doesn't show the questions for improvement anymore, IMO this question should be reopened.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am so sorry for declining this, but I really do not think there is a simple way to solve this.

As luvieere pointed out, you can still click improve even when you are out of votes.

If we were to remove the counter we would need another piece of complex per-user caching logic for the header, as it stands the counter is shared between all the users with suggested edit vote rights.

We do our best to avoid any per-user caching in the header, its tricky and hard to maintain. I follow this is a bit annoying but changing this is just not worth the effort imho.

Comment: Was the "Improve" button always there?  I forget.  I think it wasn't when I made this request...

Comment: This needs to be revisited since the new system doesn't even show you the list of questions so that you could improve them. All you see now is _You have no more suggested edit votes today; come back in 6 hours._

Comment: maybe you may at least hide it using JS (for example, using local cache after one get this message until next day)

Comment: @RiaD: great idea, why can't it just be removed using JS and `localStorage` (userscript time...)?

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I want to see the new edits, perhaps I can improve them, but I do have an issue with the Accept and Reject buttons that I can no longer use after I've exhausted my votes.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion: instead of hiding, which is tricky to the dev team, have it disabled and add tooltip saying the same message as the one you see if you visit the review suggested edits page.

Same logic is applied already for the edit link under posts: if you can't edit, the link is disabled with tooltip explaining why.