# Hide the Approve and Reject buttons for suggested edits after I run out of votes for the day

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don't display pending edit counter if you've exhausted your suggested-edit votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85366/dont-display-pending-edit-counter-if-youve-exhausted-your-suggested-edit-votes)

After I run out of votes for the day, showing me the Approve or Reject buttons is a bit confusing, as I'm tempted to press them as I check out the newest suggestions.

Could you make it so that they don't get shown after an user runs out of votes for the day?

Comment: @random My request is slightly different, I want to see new edits, perhaps I can improve them, but I do have an issue with the Accept and Reject buttons that I can no longer use.