# Don't display suggested edit counter if you've exhausted your suggested edit votes

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I know the [same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85366/dont-display-pending-edit-counter-if-youve-exhausted-your-suggested-edit-votes) has been asked (and answered), however this was prior to the latest changes to the review/suggested edits area of SO. Basically once a user has exhausted their suggestion approval/rejections vote limit, the pending edit box in the top page still shows up.

The accepted answer for the old question was to decline the request because "you can still click improve even when you are out of votes." But this no longer applies. Now when you're out of votes you get:

> You have no more suggested edit votes today; come back in 6 hours.

And have no way to even see the questions in the queue so that you might improve them. Therefore why show an alert for something to do when you can't do it?