# Don't show me the review count if I had already reached my limitation

Tags: feature-request, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don’t display pending edit counter if you’ve exhausted your suggested edit votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85366/dont-display-pending-edit-counter-if-youve-exhausted-your-suggested-edit-votes)

If I had reviewed 20 suggested edits today, and have reached the daily limit, please don't show me the number of suggested edits pending approval:

[image: Review count]

If you can't vote, this data is meaningless.