# Helpless after exhausting daily limit for reviewing Suggested Edits

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I have faced this problem earlier. But today I got to face this problem twice in a span of couple of minutes..

I have unfortunately finished my daily quota of reviewing Suggested Edits. But I want to further edit a post for which an edit has already been suggested by another user having less than 2000 Reputation.

- I come across a post and it says that an edit has already been suggested which is pending for Review:

  [image: edit pending review]
- I click on **edit (1)** and a pop-up of Suggested Edit appears:

  [image: suggested-edit]

However, the problem is this Suggested Edit doesn't thoroughly deal with the post. It just fixes some capitalization and nothing else — no grammar fixes, no sentence restructuring to make it more clear, no code formatting, no dividing it into lists, etc. — in short, perfect candidate to be rejected.

<sub>(The image for the suggested-edit I have uploaded didn't have those problems - however, there were those problems in the edits that I encountered earlier.)</sub>

The problem before me is that I am helpless. I can't approve, reject or improve the edit since I have already gone past my daily quota of Reviewing them. Neither can I make the edits to the post since this suggested edit is pending review. I am completely helpless!!

### Whats the opinion of the community in this matter?

- Should we (those with more than 2000 Rep) be able to edit them? Don't count it in our Review Progress obviously - not sure what should be done with the suggested edit already proposed.
- Or, Let it be, someone else would come and edit them and other Reviewers would deal with the Suggested Edit appropriately.
- Or, Something else.

---

#### Note:

This might not be much of a problem for Stack Overflow since the Review Queue is very busy here. However, this is a bit of a problem for smaller sites. So, treat it as a question posted at Meta.SE and not so much at Meta.SO.

---

#### Dirty Hack:

Ah... found a dirty hack to work around this situation. However, this shouldn't be used unless absolutely necessary. Credit goes to [@Gilles](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) in [this comment](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1151/why-cant-i-edit-a-question-i-have-reviewed#comment1677_1151).

To edit a post enter this link in your browser: `http://${site_url}/posts/${post_id}/edit`. So, to edit this particular post one would enter: `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/171129/edit`.

I repeat, the hack shouldn't be used unless necessary.

Comment: ok, then it's just me being a newby at meta site's :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164853/remove-20-reviews-per-day-for-people-who-gained-gold-badge-for-that-review-type and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164856/dont-show-me-the-review-count-if-i-had-already-reached-my-limitation

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The limit is there for a reason. My suggestion:

1. Bookmark the post.
2. Now, go outside, take your dogs for a walk, spend time with your kids, do your taxes, clean the garage, watch a movie...
3. Tomorrow, revisit the post. If it's still in bad shape, edit it.

It is not the end of the world to leave one post on StackOverflow imperfect, or to let a half-baked edit go through (or, more likely, be rejected by someone else who cares as much as you do). With the volume on this site that would be like trying to correct every wrong person on the Internet. And on smaller sites, *shrug*, you can always fix it later. The fact that you're hitting the cap on a smaller site suggests you should read point 2. above again.

Comment: You are suggesting **Let it be**. Now lets see if someone comes and says **we should be able to edit them**... However, your suggestion to bookmark was excellent... It didn't occur to me at all... :-)

Comment: `The fact that you're hitting the cap on a smaller site suggests you should read point 2. above again` This makes so much sense :)

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of bookmarking it for a later time. I use tab groups in FFox and have a group with only SO pages for specifically that purpose.

Comment: I use Google Tasks for this (I also use it for Ima-keep-an-eye-on-you and please-fix-this posts on sites I moderate)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact reason behind this, just some of my thoughts:

- Review edits does not only mean that queue that is shown on the mod tools, it means reviewing edits in general, the queue is just a tool to see edits quickly (go through ever post to find `edit(n)` is useless time)
- When we accept edits to be done by 2000+ users while there is already a proposal from a 2000- user, you can get nasty conflicts. I think it is better to *not* do that.
- Does unable to edit one post mean 'helpless'? There are a lot of other things to do! Such as improving other posts, really, just 1% have these proposal edits or fixing the long closing  votes queue.

Comment: `there is already a proposal from a 2000- user` Only user with less than 2k rep can suggest edit. About editing, you still get the normal conflict due to race condition when editing normally anyway.

Comment: (1) I have exhausted my daily quota of reviewing Suggested Edit (so it doesn't show the edits which are pending for review to me). Mod Tools doesn't come into the picture at all. I don't go around finding posts having `edit(n)` - I have chanced upon such posts (3 to be precise in a span of about 10 minutes). (3) There are people like me who like to edit posts, to try to make it more clear for the next person who reads it, I am not a great answerer, so finding posts which needs fixing gives me more satisfaction and hence I feel helpless!! :-)