# Impossible to edit a question with a suggested edit

Tags: discussion, bug, edits, review, suggested-edits

Apparently it is impossible to edit a question that has a pending suggested edit. I have reached the limit on how many suggested edits I can review today, so I suddenly cannot edit the question. This is really stupid.

Normally I can edit a question in the most extreme situations: when another editor has finished just before I did, or when there is a suggested edit made *after* I opened the edit form. However, when I have to (re)open the edit form and there is a pending suggested edit *and* I have reached my edit review limit, then I am suddenly not allowed to edit.

This looks like an unintended side-effect of the daily suggested-edit review limit. Of course I understand that the suggested edit should be reviewed before I continue with my edit; therefore **I suggest that the edit review limit is *not* applied when the question is viewed directly** (instead of via the *review* queues).

Or maybe even better, as [Back in a flash suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172372/192172#comment511354_172372), to **allow the suggested edit to be improved** even when the edit review limit has been reached. That way one can combine my intended edit with the suggested edit.

Comment: I'd opt for having atleast the improve button.

Comment: @BackinaFlash That would also be a good idea instead. That way I can combine my edit with the suggested edit.

Comment: Related [Helpless after exhausting daily limit for reviewing Suggested Edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171129/208592)

Comment: The related question does not have an answer (certainly not like [the answer below](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172374/192172)).

Answer (score 4):

There is a way around this. When there is a suggested edit on the post, the edit link is replaced with the text "edit (1)", and links to reviewing the suggested edit rather than to the edit page. However, the edit page is still accessible. You can manually enter the URL to it, but if you are really lucky, someone may have dropped the edit link into a comment suggesting that the post be edited.

If you don't feel like manually entering the link, and aren't fortunate enough to have an edit link in the comments, there is still hope! The edit link is a magic comment link! Simply post a comment containing "[edit]", and your comment will appear with a link to edit the post. Example:

> I would like to [edit] this post!

**Important:** Note that editing the post while a suggested edit is pending may have unintended consequences, such as rejecting the edit.

Comment: In action: You can click the link in this comment to [edit] my answer.

Comment: If you do this won't it auto reject the suggested edit though?

Comment: Yes; I believe I mentioned that.

Comment: **Note:** Please only do this if the suggested edit that currently stands deserves to be rejected. It's not fair to users to get a rejected edit just because you're impatient and there's no feature to address the situation. I'd consider it a bug that you're even *allowed* to do this, and it certainly should be prevented.

Comment: @animuson Does that edit capture your concern?

Comment: @Jim: I was just pointing out that even though a user may know that, they still *shouldn't* use this method to bypass the system unless they're absolutely certain the existing edit should be rejected anyways.