# Can I disable review tools notification after I don't have any more flags/votes left

Tags: feature-request, review, 10k-tools

[image]

While I love the access to [moderator-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) I receive because of crossing the [10k mark](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), I'd seriously like to disable this once I've used up all of my close-votes, reopen votes and delete votes.

[image: Image 2]

Since I can no longer help with the edits/close votes, can I not be bothered with that notification.

The reasons I want this disabled/hidden are:

1. I can only chose to deny the flags now, which I don't like to do.
2. When suggested edits notification shows up and I still have to wait 16 hours for this, it seems annoying(this has been previously asked too).
3. (**MOST IMPORTANT**) The browser takes ~5 times the time it used to load the page now. Previously, the page was generated within 3-4 seconds while now it takes at-least 20 seconds.

Comment: Not 100% the same question, but the answer there applies to here as well.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha A cookie perhaps can be stored and checked on for every refresh. Since it'll be on client side, no complex queries on server side required. Plus, two years have passed since that request. I'm sure there must've been some new improvement in these two years.

Comment: Don't tell that to me, tell it to the developer who declined the answer on that one. I [requested the exact same feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164856/dont-show-me-the-review-count-if-i-had-already-reached-my-limitation).