# Moderator Elections: Nomination link without necessary badges

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, moderation, election

I am wondering why the self nomination link is accessible for users who don't have the necessary badges for such. The link takes you to the self nomination form and afterwards correctly does not allow you to submit it.

I believe the link should not be visible at all.

**Update:**

Great, now the link is no longer present, however a very small improvement can be made IMO: to show only the names of the badges the user is missing.

Comment: Should probably be a [tag:feature-request].

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I will retag, thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After the next build we will check for the necessary badges prior to allowing self nomination.

Comment: Great now it shows a message about the required badges. Maybe a small tweak can be done to show the names only of the badges you're missing :)

Answer (score 0):

My (educated) guess is, checking for each user to see if he's legible is expensive. It's much more practical to display the link for everybody and display an error message when an illegible user tries it.

This is based off an answer we got for a similar question on a different topic: [Don't display pending edit counter if you've exhausted your suggested edit votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85366/dont-display-pending-edit-counter-if-youve-exhausted-your-suggested-edit-votes)

Comment: It shouldn't be expensive to make a request and check status as soon as the link is clicked, and would save users the trouble of writing out an entire nomination summary only to find they are ineligible.

Comment: @Asad: Users, **especially** mod candidates (or those who want to be ones) are expected to make the most basic action of *reading*. If they fail doing that, I don't know if I want them as a moderator in the first place. If you fail to read the instructions, don't be surprised it came biting you back from behind. SE does not encourage laziness.