# Question pointing to wrong question when not logged in

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, login, logout, redirection

I found this really weird bug just now... In here the question link is redirected to wrong question when you  are not logged-in, but when you log in again everything seems fine...

take a look here...

Steps:-

- Visit [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=review%20queue) in logged off condition
- Find a question 
  **Q:Review queue in the topbar makes a man sad when he can't act upon it [duplicate]**
- Click on that question.. It redirects to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85366/dont-display-pending-edit-counter-if-youve-exhausted-your-suggested-edit-votes)
- Now loggin again.. you are then redirected to correct question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a question is closed as a duplicate of another one, anonymous users are redirected to the "original" question on the assumption that it will answer their question.

This assumption doesn't *always* hold true since it's possible for a question to be wrongly closed, but the risk of that is relatively low when it comes to duplicate closures.

Comment: I didn't knew this happens.. Thanks for clearing..

Comment: Why are we not informed of this anywhere?

Comment: @ColeJohnson What do you mean? It's documented on meta like pretty much everything else.